# How to use rotativa Print PDF in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm tried using Rotativa for printing the page as Pdf, but it download as Pdf instead as printable pdf. Is there any other way for printing the page. Here is my code.

```
 public ActionResult PrintInvoice(int invoiceId = 0)
    {
        return new ActionAsPdf(
                       "Invoice",
                       new { invoiceId = invoiceId }) { FileName = "Invoice.pdf" };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayby late, but I had the same problem.
You can use:
    return new ViewAsPdf(invoice);

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "FileName" like this (Below). It should print the pdf instead download it.

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(int invoiceId = 0)
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Invoice", new { invoiceId = invoiceId });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this alternative way.

```
    public ActionResult PrintInvoice(int invoiceId = 0)        
    {
         return new ViewAsPdf("Invoice", new { invoiceId = invoiceId });
    }
```